# Acumatica MoveEntry API not generating lot number

Tags: acumatica

Has anyone here used the PUT /MoveEntry call successfully before? I can make the call to create the record, but I was expecting the API to populate the lot number and it is not. It does by UI, but not by API. Is there a trick that I'm missing?

**Update 1:**

```
PUT /MoveEntry
{
    "Hold": {
        "value": true
    },
    "Details": [
        {
            "OrderType": {
                "value": "RO"
            },
            "ProductionNbr": {
                "value": "RO0000001"
            },
            "Quantity": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "Location": {
                "value": "PRODRECPT"
            },
            "Warehouse": {
                "value": "ABBOTSFORD"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It always records the document successfully, but never has the lot number.

Could it be a lot class configuration issue?

[image]

**Update 2**:
Acu support agrees this looks like a defect and has passed the case on to Acu development.

Comment: I just tried this locally and it seem to work on my side.
What Acumatica version are you using and what is the request that you are making (URL and body)

Comment: Thanks for checking, that gives me hope! I'm on version 20.211.0037

Comment: @samol518 - I added to the description more details about the url, body, and lot class configuration for the SKU in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with Acu Support, it came back the API requires the "OperationNbr" field to be populated with the Bill of Materials operation number. Then the lot number is generated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Numbering Sequence called AMBatch as that is the one that seems to be used by default for me on the Move Entry screen.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The AMBATCH seems to be about creating the move document number, not the lot number. I posted a support ticket with Acu on this, but they are extremely busy lately.